# How to browse the web safely with Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: security, firefox

i want to know how can i possibly keep me secured from forgery sites. i am currently using mozilla 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use wot ( web of trust) plugin for firefox.it will keep you secure to some extent from forgery sites...

Comment: do **NOT install WOT**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html

Answer (score 12):

**Firefox 3** or later contains built-in Phishing and Malware Protection to help keep you safe online. These features will warn you when a page you visit has been reported as a Web Forgery of a legitimate site (sometimes called “phishing” pages) or as an Attack Site designed to harm your computer (otherwise known as malware).

**[image][SOURCE](https://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/phishing-protection/)**

**NOTE:**
You can also install the following **Add-ons** for **Firefox**, for secure browsing.With flash and scripting off, all that is left in browser is html and images and these are not too dangerous.

**[Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433/)**  **[NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722/)**  **[Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/)**

Answer (score 6):

Add-Ins for enhanced security:

[NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722/)

[AdBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/)

[HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your browsing history regularly.

Use strong passwords for websites and Ubuntu (login) accounts. Remember to log out from the websites after using them. Lock your screen if you leave your PC unattended.

Comment: Why would clearing your history increase your protection against *phishing* (i.e., "forgery sites")?