# Can I use linux safely and sell on ebay?

Tags: security

I sell things on ebay here and there and I have always used windows.  Is linux safe enough to do my ebay dealings?  Is there anything related to linux I need to download to be keep passwords and money safe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

A couple of years ago, ComputerWorld author Robert Mitchell made some waves with an article titled "[Can Ubuntu Save Online Banking?](http://blogs.computerworld.com/15815/can_ubuntu_save_online_banking)"  The premise of the article isn't anything really pro-Linux or anti-Windows.  But rather that conducting online banking from the same PC used (by your entire family) for web surfing puts you at-risk of any dormant malware designed to steal bank information.  As a remedy, the author recommends using an Ubuntu Live CD for online banking, and even suggests that some banks might start handing them out to customers.

My point with referencing this article, is that if security experts are recommending using Ubuntu (albeit, on a live CD) for banking, then you should be ok on EBay.  As others have said, you should be fine with Ubuntu out-of-the-box.  I've used Ubuntu for online banking, EBay, shopping, etc for several years now, and never had a problem.

Comment: The fact that you haven't had any problems yet does not prove much. Still, I would recommand using Ubuntu because it's both reputed stable and less used (thus less targeted by attackers) than win7

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase...  I've been using Ubuntu at home since 7.10  and I've never had malware on my Ubuntu machines.  I believe that this is due to the fact that the Linux security model is vastly superior to the one in-place on Windows.  Ubuntu also takes extra steps, like prohibiting you from logging on as "root" from the GUI.  On the other hand, my Windows-using friends and family have not been quite as lucky.

Answer (score 5):

Brian,

I started using Linux right around the same time that I started selling on Ebay.  I have not ran into any issues and absolutely love Linux.

In the Ubuntu Software Center there is a tool known as esniper which is a lightweight ebay sniping tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, it should be safe out of the box so to speak? No add-ons and such?

Comment: I believe whole-heartedly that you will be safe out of the box.  Just make sure you take the necessary precautions in protecting your username/passwords, etc.  I also run my Paypal account with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ebay is a website so make sure that your browser is safe. Uninstall plugins that you don't need. You should install the HTTPS Everywhere pluign which makes sure that the browser uses an HTTPS connection if it's supported by the website. You should also remove your browsing history after using Ebay.

Use strong passwords for your Ebay and Ubuntu (login) accounts. Remember to log out from Ebay after using it. Lock your screen if you leave your PC unattended.

This [queston](https://askubuntu.com/q/16032/8973) has more tips on making Firefox for more secure.

Comment: I have add-ons installed. Will they steal my information?

Comment: Add-ons on the Mozilla sites are verified but read the add-ons's terms of service and privacy police if it provides a service (eg password sync).